# Do we need to specifically call previous state to retain previous values?

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a state like so:

```
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState({
    bDay: new Date(),
    anniversary: new Date(),
  });
```

Let us suppose I want to retain bDay and change anniversary date would I need to copy the previous state to change only part of it?

Like so:

```
    setDropdowns(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    anniversary: new Date(datefrom4yearsago) 
  }))
```

or can I just set the state for only the one I want and the state will be kept the same for all other object entries?

```
setDropdowns({anniversary: new Date(datefrom4yearsago)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With hooks one doesn't merge state anymore as in the case of `this.setState`, one overrides the state. So you have to use `prevState` if you only want to change one property of your state object.

Comment: Great, ok that was my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, **useState does not automatically merge update objects**. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

```
setState(prevState => {
   // Object.assign would also work
   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```